# Ruby storing classes inside a hash

Tags: ruby, curl

How can I store a class of type `Net::HTTP::Get` inside hashes?
I have multiple curl requests like :

```
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new("https://api.randomsite.com")
#or
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new("https://api.randomsite.com")
```

I 'm trying to do something like that :

```
REQUESTS = {
     get:    Net::HTTP::Get.new,
     post:   Net::HTTP::Post.new,
     patch:  Net::HTTP::Patch.new
}
def request(req, uri)
    request = public_send(REQUESTS[req.to_sym],uri)
end

#call :

request("get","https://api.randomsite.com")
```

But I keep getting errors `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2))`. I tried to not initialize the classes but then I get : `TypeError (Net::HTTP::Get is not a symbol nor a string)`

I want to do it the same way we do it for storing methods :

```
TEST = {
        one: :step_one_function,
        two: :step_two_function
}

def step_one_function(param)
        puts "1 #{param.to_s}"
end

def step_two_function(param)
        puts "2 #{param.to_s}"
end

public_send(TEST[:one],"hello")
```

Or is there any other similar way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you're creating a new `Net::HTTP::[Get|Post|Patch]` but you're not passing the arguments you need for that;

```
Net::HTTP::Get.new
`initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2) (ArgumentError)
```

The error there tells you you need at least 1 argument (and maximum 2) to create a new `Net::HTTP::Get` object. The same happens with the others.

To make that work somehow, you can use `method`, and return a new `Method` object, which you can then invoke the method it holds by passing the proper arguments:

```
REQUESTS = {
  get: Net::HTTP::Get.method(:new),
  post: Net::HTTP::Post.method(:new),
  patch: Net::HTTP::Patch.method(:new)
}.freeze

def request(req, uri)
  REQUESTS[req.to_sym].(uri)
end

request("get","https://api.randomsite.com")
# #<Net::HTTP::Get GET>
```

There `.()` is the method invokation. What `Net::HTTP::Get.method(:new)` returns can then be "called" (using `uri` as the argument in this case). Similarly `[]` and `call`;

```
REQUESTS[req.to_sym].(uri)
# #<Net::HTTP::Get GET>
REQUESTS[req.to_sym][uri]
# #<Net::HTTP::Get GET>
REQUESTS[req.to_sym].call(uri)
# #<Net::HTTP::Get GET>
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I don't like the whole idea of this code:

```rb
REQUESTS = {
     get:    Net::HTTP::Get.new,
     post:   Net::HTTP::Post.new,
     patch:  Net::HTTP::Patch.new
}
def request(req, uri)
    request = public_send(REQUESTS[req.to_sym],uri)
end
```

But assuming you do have reasons to design it this way it requires a couple of fixes - just keep constants (classes) as hash values and instantiate them (handlers) on the fly. So, smth. like this:

```rb
REQUEST_HANDLERS = {
  get:    Net::HTTP::Get,
  post:   Net::HTTP::Post,
  patch:  Net::HTTP::Patch
}.freeze

def request(req, uri)
  REQUEST_HANDLERS.fetch(req.to_sym).new(uri)
end
```

(I'm using `fetch` to force failure for any unknown request - change this if you'd prefer "swallowing" this kind of errors)